# Unable to use python 2 in Ubuntu

Tags: python

When I type `python2`, an error appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "tensorflow/venv/lib/python3.6/site.py", line 67, in <module>
  import os
File "tensorflow/venv/lib/python3.6/os.py", line 409
  yield from walk(new_path, topdown, onerror, followlinks)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You seem to use a Python 3.6 venv with Python 2.7.

Comment: Why would `python2` be running `venv/lib/python3.6`?

Comment: What should I do to use Python 2.7?

Comment: Install it properly?

Comment: Can I change PYTHONPATH or bashrc?

Comment: If you are using `venv` you should probably deactivate it first.

Comment: I haven't activate `venv`. Is the problem caused by python2 trying to find the os.py of python3?

Comment: `yield from` is a Py3 feature.  You ca  ot run this `tensorflow` script with python2.  Do you have `tensorflow` installed for py2?